# Elastic beanstalk: Failed to buld docker image

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Django application to Elastic Beanstalk (AWS). I've started a new Django project from scratch.

When I try to deploy the application, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: ime="2015-04-02T16:04:13Z" level="info" msg="The command
[/bin/sh -c if [ -f /var/app/requirements.txt ]; then /var/app/bin/pip install -r /var/app/requirements.txt; fi] returne
d a non-zero code: 2" . Check snapshot logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-b9cd0c44 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 O
utput: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeansta
lk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh
```

I've tried to keep my project and configuration as basic as possible (still haven't been able to deploy a single django app through AWS, trying to understand what I'm doing wrong..).

In my root folder I have the .ebextensions folder, with the following config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:    
    command: "python testsite/manage.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: testsite.settings
```

I've had to set the WSGIPath variable directly through the elastic beanstalk web GUI - for some reason setting it through the config file just didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first error appears to be from the `docker build` process. The second error is likely because `03build.sh` is the script that Elastic Beanstalk uses to call the `docker build`. Are you able to post the `Dockerfile`? Does the Docker image build locally fine?

Comment: How do I find the Dockerfile? AFAIK using the docker is something elastic beanstalk is just doing automatically - I haven't been building any docker images locally. All I've done is to setup a new, blank django project, added an .ebextensions folder with the config file above, and tried to deploy using the "eb deploy" command. I'm fairly new to all this, but I've been following the steps on this site: https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Ah, I mis-understood. I thought you were running a Docker image based on the `docker` tag. Maybe EB is building the Python project as a Docker container under the covers.

Does the `eb logs` command contain any of the pip logs? The error actually states to `Check snapshot logs for details.`. It might be helpful to post the logs if any.

Comment: @rcca any progress on this? I'm getting the same error and am also running django from that tutorial. Sounds like it's something wrong with the tutorial?

Comment: @awwester I actually gave up on AWS, since I managed to get my project running on Heroku instead (which was also giving me troubles in the beginning due to some of my dependencies). I too think there might be something wrong with the tutorial, or something wrong with AWS' pre-configured docker setup for django, but I really don't know. Maybe if you post your AWS logs someone might be able to figure it out?

Comment: FYI - It seems something is wrong with the CLI, possibly the preconfigured Docker not being set up correctly like you suggested. I deployed through the web console instead of CLI and it worked.